# I need to return a variable from a jquery function

Tags: jquery, function, return

I need to return a variable from a function

```
function getdatabasesize() {
    name = "t";
    var test
    $.post(
        'ajax/getlastfilenumber.php',
        { name: name }, 
        function(data) {    
            test = data;
        });
        return test;
    }
```

Then to call this I use something like

```
alert(getdatabasesize());
```

or

```
var test = getdatabasesize()
```

but all I get is `undefined`. I want to use this to get the last record number in my database you see.

Comment: Remember, the first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous. `return test` is hit before `test` is set in the AJAX callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can return promise interface from function and then use specific methods on it:

```
function getdatabasesize() {
    name = "t";
    return $.post(
        'ajax/getlastfilenumber.php', {
        name: name
    });
}

getdatabasesize().done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted?

Comment: Just code, no explaination, maybe that's it

Comment: Hi A. Wolff, What you posted works, however I cannot use data outside the scope of getdatabasesize. I am really new to jquery, so I am not 100percent certain how to get things to work. However I know programming and php, so I should be able to get my head around this. I tried creating a var outside the scope and using that, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Set an outer scoped (global?) variable e.g `var test;` and affect value in done() callback. Still in done() callback, call function(s) to use this new variable value. This is how you have to deal with async methods.